# Is possible to decide which bean use depending on path variables with @Autowire?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm playing around with Spring these days and I got stuck trying to autowire beans during the HTTP request lifetime.

I have an interface called `Animal` and two implementations, `Dog` and `Cat` as follows:

**Animal.java**

```java
public interface Animal {
  public String sound();
}
```

**Dog.java**

```java
public class Dog implements Animal {
  @Override
  public String sound() {return "Woof!";}
}
```

**Cat.java**

```java
public class Cat implements Animal {
  @Override
  public String sound() {return "Meow... :3";}
}
```

My controller looks like this:

**AnimalController.jav**a

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/animal")
public class AnimalController {
  private final AnimalService animalService;

  @Autowired
  public AnimalController(AnimalService service) {
    animalService = service;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/{animal}/sound")
  public String animalSound(@PathVariable String animal) {
    return animalService.doSound();
  }
}
```

**AnimalService.java** (Here I cant autowire my animals):

```java
@Service
public class AnimalService {

/* 
 My IDE prompts:  
 'Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of `Animal` type.'
*/
  @Autowired
  private Animal animal; 

  public String doSound() {
    return animal.sound();
  }
}    
}
```

Also:

**Configuration.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
  @Bean
  public Dog createDog() {
    return new Dog();
  }

  @Bean
  public Cat createCat() {
    return new Cat();
  }
}
```

Is possible to have this behavior of deciding which bean use depending on path variables? I tried read the core documentation of Spring, but I couldn't understand too much. I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the animal bean from Container by the beanName;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/animal")
public class AnimalController {

private final AnimalService animalService;

  @Autowired
  public AnimalController(AnimalService service) {
    animalService = service;
  }


  @GetMapping(value = "/{animal}/sound")
  public String animalSound(@PathVariable String animal) {
    return animalService.doSound(animal);
  }

}
```

AnimalService.java

```
public class AnimalService implements ApplicationContextAware {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}


public String doSound(String animalName) {
    Animal animal = applicationContext.getBean(animalName);
return animal.sound();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instantiate all beans of type `Animal` by making them a list.
Ex:

```
@Autowired
List<Animal> animals;
```

This is going to autowire all animals, and you can iterate through them and decide programatically which one you need.

Although, I may be wrong, but for your use case I believe a Factory design pattern would fit better. You can make an abstract `AnimalFactory` and autowire all factories in a list, then apply some sort of strategy pattern to decide programatically which factory you are going to use and return a new object of that type.

Comment: I was thinking about it. My previous solution was using a supplier to decide which animal to use, but someone asked me to try using Spring IoC instead. I think that I can't do it in this case.

Comment: Just a note: I missed it, but @jin has covered it in his answer. If you don't need a factory and just need a certain bean by it's class or name, you can get beans from `ApplicationContext` by their name or type respectively

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring.profiles.active to do it. One profile loads the dog the other the cat.

```
  @Configuration
public class Configuration {

@Profile("dog")
  @Bean
  public Dog createDog() {
    return new Dog();
  }

@Profile("cat")
  @Bean
  public Cat createCat() {
    return new Cat();
  }
}
```

And you can start your app like java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=dog.

The other option you can give it a try is to Qualify the beans and use a Qualifier with a property variable, spring may resolves it.

```
@Service
public class AnimalService {

  @Qualifier("${choosen.animal}")
  @Autowired
  private Animal animal; 

  public String doSound() {
    return animal.sound();
  }
}    
}
```

Comment: The key thing is that I want to decide which bean to use when someone perform the following request: 

`GET /animal/{animal}/sound`

Deciding with the `animal` path variable.